# How to redirect few urls http to https?

Tags: https

I have tried searching here but nothing worked for me. I have Joomla site and want to redirect some site urls (3-4) to use HTTPS traffic to process credit card payments. Can you please guide me how can i do it using .htaccess file? what would be the exact code?

I do not want whole site to run over ssl https but few pages.

I want these:

http://www.domain.com/city1/store
http://www.domain.com/city2/subcity/store

to use https.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
RewriteRule "^/folder(/.*)" "https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1" [R=301,L]
```

Look more on [htaccess HTTPS](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/ssl-example-usage-in-htaccess.html#redirect-urls-to-ssl)

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I do not want to run whole site over ssl. I only need to redirect 3-4 urls to https. How can i do that?